# Frequency of Words within Cells within Range

Tags: excel, vba, text

I have a column of about 50 cells. Each cell contains a block of text, anywhere from 3-8 sentences.

Id like to populate a list of words being used and obtain their frequencies for the entire range (A1:A50).

Ive tried to manipulate other codes I've found in other posts but they seem to be tailored to cells that contain one word rather than multiple words.

This is the code I found that I was attempting to use.

```
Sub Ftable()
Dim BigString As String, I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
Dim Selection As Range

Set Selection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A")
BigString = ""
For Each r In Selection
     BigString = BigString & " " & r.Value
Next r
BigString = Trim(BigString)
ary = Split(BigString, " ")
Dim cl As Collection
Set cl = New Collection
For Each a In ary
    On Error Resume Next
    cl.Add a, CStr(a)
Next a

For I = 1 To cl.Count
    v = cl(I)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(I, "B").Value = v
    J = 0
    For Each a In ary
        If a = v Then J = J + 1
    Next a
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(I, "C") = J
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: When you try this code, what exactly happens? It seems to me that this could theoretically work for your situation, but that your BigString is likely growing too large for VBA to handle correctly (it really doesn't like long strings). If this is the case, you'll probably need to rewrite the code significantly (in the least you'll have to loop through the selected cells instead of tackling them all at once).

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, a dictionary is the best way to handle this I think as you can test if the dictionary already contains an item. Post back if there's anything you don't get.

```
Sub CountWords()

Dim dictionary As Object
Dim sentence() As String
Dim arrayPos As Integer
Dim lastRow, rowCounter As Long
Dim ws, destination As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Put the source sheet name here")
Set destination = Sheets("Put the destination sheet name here")

rowCounter = 2
arrayPos = 0
lastRow = ws.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row

Set dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")

For x = 2 To lastRow
    sentence = Split(ws.Cells(x, 1), " ")
    For y = 0 To UBound(sentence)
        If Not dictionary.Exists(sentence(y)) Then
            dictionary.Add sentence(y), 1
        Else
            dictionary.Item(sentence(y)) = dictionary.Item(sentence(y)) + 1
        End If
    Next y
Next x

For Each Item In dictionary
    destination.Cells(rowCounter, 1) = Item
    destination.Cells(rowCounter, 2) = dictionary.Item(Item)
    rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
Next Item

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (works for me with some long blocks of Lorem Ipsum text):

```
Sub Ftable()
Dim BigString As String, I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
Dim countRange As Range

Set countRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A50")
BigString = ""
For Each r In countRange.Cells
     BigString = BigString & " " & r.Value
Next r
BigString = Trim(BigString)
ary = Split(BigString, " ")
Dim cl As Collection
Set cl = New Collection
For Each a In ary
    On Error Resume Next
    cl.Add a, CStr(a)
Next a

For I = 1 To cl.Count
    v = cl(I)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(I, "B").Value = v
    J = 0
    For Each a In ary
        If a = v Then J = J + 1
    Next a
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(I, "C") = J
Next I
End Sub
```

I took it down to only looking at the 50 cells where you have data, as opposed to all >1 million in that column. I also fixed an issue where r was getting a length 1 array instead of a Range. And I renamed "Selection" to "countRange" because Selection is already defined in the application, so it was bad naming.

Also, notice that your code pulls from "Sheet1" and outputs into columns B and C of "Sheet2". Make sure you rename your worksheets or edit these values, or you'll get errors/data corruption.

---

This is how I'd approach the problem:

```
Sub Ftable()
Dim wordDict As New Dictionary
Dim r As Range
Dim countRange As Range
Dim str As Variant
Dim strArray() As String

Set countRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A50")

For Each r In countRange
    strArray = Split(Trim(r.Value), " ")

    For Each str In strArray
        str = LCase(str)
        If wordDict.Exists(str) Then
            wordDict(str) = wordDict(str) + 1
        Else
            wordDict.Add str, 1
        End If
    Next str
Next r

Set r = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")
For Each str In wordDict.Keys()
    r.Value = str
    r.Offset(0, 1).Value = wordDict(str)
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
Next str

Set wordDict = Nothing
End Sub
```

It uses a dictionary, so make sure you add a reference to the library (Tools > Add Reference > Microsoft Scripting Library). It also forces everything to lowercase - one big issue of the old code was that it failed to count capitalized and uncapitalized versions correctly, meaning it missed many words. Remove `str = LCase(str)` if you don't want this.

Bonus: this method ran about 8 times faster on my test sheet.

Comment: I am getting an error on this line: cl.Add a, CStr(a). The error states "This key is already associated with an element of this collection

Comment: ... That makes no sense. The line directly before it is instructing the code to suppress any errors and continue executing as if nothing bad happened. For some reason the error isn't being suppressed for you... Hold on, I'm whipping up a better version of this anyway.